# Error 403 when creating Cloud Dataproc cluster - permission denied

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

When I am creating a [Google Cloud Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc) cluster I am getting an error 403 `PERMISSION_DENIED` error. The exact text of the error is:

```
{
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Failed to authorize Cloud Platform service-account for projectId '<project-id>':
    ...
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
```

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rare occur which can occur when the API activation for Cloud Dataproc fails. While rare, this is a pretty easy problem to fix. You need to disable and then re-enable the Dataproc API.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Log into the [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com)
2. On the left under `APIs & auth` click `APIs`
3. Click on the `Enabled APIs` tab at the top of the page
4. From the list of APIs select `Google Cloud Dataproc API`
5. Click on the `Disable API` button
6. In the window which asks you to confirm, click `Disable`
7. Click on the `Enable API` button to turn it back on

Now the API should be re-enabled and the problem should be resolved.

Comment: This doesn't always work. Seems to be a bug where Disabling the API silently fails, and it remains Enabled.

Comment: @polleyg Looks like this is a bug beyond Dataproc with Cloud Platform. We're bugging the powers that be to fix.

Answer (score 1):

If Disabling/Enabling the Dataproc API will not work (it did not work for me), try creating a new project in the console - if it's feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that you just open the Compute Engine on the left of [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Wait for it to do some initial work and then, it shows you can create VM.

Then, the problem may be solved. Good luck!